# How to getState() in Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have the following slice and function. How can I get values stored in my initialState?

```
const example = createSlice({
  name: "example",
  initialState: {
   firstName: hello,
   lastName: world
  },
  reducers: {}
 })

export const create = (id) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
      const currentState = getState()
      console.log(currentState) 
  };
};
```

Do I have to use useSelector and pass values down to the function again? Ideally would like to get data directly from the already saved state

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
export const create = (id) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
       const currentState= getState().example;
      console.log(currentState) 
  };
};
```

You can access the slice state using the above code.

Comment: if you want to get access to "firstName" or "lastName", you can use:

`export const create = (id) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {

       const firstName= getState().example.firstName;

      console.log(firstName) 
  };
};`

Comment: Is this safe to do? Eg are values memoized and all that jazz? I can't find any info on this in the official docs :/

Comment: Yes it's highlighted in their docs but the results wont be momized, you will need to do something else e.g. https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors